# Need help in deciphering NFC AAR code

Tags: android, uri, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I've started learning more about AAR and NFC and found this neat piece of code working. However, I have trouble understanding what it really does and is it already adding in the AAR into the NDEF message. Can someone guide me on what line of code does what? Thanks a lot!

```
private NdefMessage getTagAsNdef() {  
    boolean addAAR = false;  
    String uniqueId = "ichatime.com";      
    byte[] uriField = uniqueId.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));  
    byte[] payload = new byte[uriField.length + 1];       //add 1 for the URI Prefix  
    payload[0] = 0x01;                        //prefixes http://www. to the URI  
    System.arraycopy(uriField, 0, payload, 1, uriField.length); //appends URI to payload  
    NdefRecord rtdUriRecord = new NdefRecord(  
    NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_URI, new byte[0], payload);  
    if(addAAR) {  
        // note: returns AAR for different app (nfcreadtag)  
        return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {  
               rtdUriRecord, NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("com.example.ponpon")  
             });   
    } else {  
       return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {  
                       rtdUriRecord});  
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

An AAR is a form of External Type Record, for which you can download the spec from nfc-forum.org. An external type consists of three pieces of data:

- Domain
- Type
- Value

I've written a library [project](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) which provides high-level NDEF record objects, which also includes external type records.

There is also a template for using NFC in activities you might be interested in :-)

Comment: Cannot get simpler, than using your NDEF tools library :)